# Use of object pronouns after the verb "to be" and in the presence of a conjunction.

Tags: grammar

The other day my friend and I were playing darts with several other players.  We selected teams.  When I learned that my partner would be Jordan, I enthusiastically announced,

"Hey Jordan, it's you and me!"

My friend objected that I should have said "Hey Jordan, it's you and I," for the same reason that one announces at the door of a friend who wonders who is outside, "It is I."

I find "It is I" rather pompous, but it seems correct.  "Hey Jordan, it's you and I," on the other hand, seems incorrect.  What is the rule here?

Comment: It all depends on whether you want to talk English, or the made-up language which Robert Lowth invented in his _Short Introduction dto English Grammar_ in 1762. The English for "It is I" is, and has always been  "it's me", but Lowth misled generations of teachers into torturing their pupils into speaking an artificial language with "It is I". _A fortiori_, the English for "It's you and I" is "It's you and me".